# Exception: Could not synchronize database state with session

Tags: hibernate, session, sequence, unique-constraint, ora-00001

I have an web application developed on spring and hibernate 3.0 and deployed on apache tomcat 6.
I am getting below error when I am trying to insert the data to the one of the table ('CAR_ATTRIBUTE' table).

```
    [CAR] [2010-12-12 13:41:30,651] ERROR [http-80-2] AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(301) | Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.test.model.CarAttribute]
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2267)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2660)
        at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:558)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:662)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:632)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:319)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy31.resyncAttributes(Unknown Source)
       ...
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController.processFormSubmission(SimpleFormController.java:267)
        at com.belk.car.app.webapp.controller.BaseFormController.processFormSubmission(BaseFormController.java:169)
        at com.belk.car.app.webapp.controller.DashBoardFormController.processFormSubmission(DashBoardFormController.java:176)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:265)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:874)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:808)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:441)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
        at org.appfuse.webapp.filter.StaticFilter.doFilterInternal(StaticFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:75)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:118)
        at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:164)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:406)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.appfuse.webapp.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilterInternal(LocaleFilter.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:75)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:75)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
        at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
        at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:166)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:75)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:735)
Caused by:
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CARS.XAK1CAR_ATTRIBUTE) violated

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:602)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9350)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:210)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.addToBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:34)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2247)
        ... 96 more
```

This error is only reproducable at production environment. Same code is working on my local environment pointing to same DB.
I tried adding logger statement and found that sequence generator is generating same value , i.e '0' each time.
Awaiting for ur help.

-- Sun2

---

Thanks for reply. Yes, Exception clearly says its violating the constrains. CARS.XAK1CAR_ATTRIBUTE is combined key and it should be unique. I have validated all the data (by loggers) and could not found the data which can violate this constrains.  Moreover if it is violating this constrains then it should not work on my local  environment pointing to same DB. 
Can this be server specific?
I can provide more details like table DDL and data which I am trying to insert, If it can help to solve the issue. 
--Santosh

Answer (score 2):

without knowing more about what specifically you are doing on this save, all I can say is that the answer is in the stack trace

```
unique constraint (CARS.XAK1CAR_ATTRIBUTE) violated
```

you are violating some sort of constraint.  Perhaps you are saving when you mean to be updating?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, Exception clearly says its violating the constrains. CARS.XAK1CAR_ATTRIBUTE is combined key and it should be unique. I have validated all the data (by loggers) and could not found the data which can violate this constrains.  Moreover if it is violating this constrains then it should not work on my local environment pointing to same DB.

Comment: @sun2, do you have the same data in your dev environment as production?  Have you stepped thru the code in a debugger?

Comment: Yes.. I have same data on my dev environment as production. Moreover I tried even with production DB. I got same errors.

Comment: @sun2, you mean you tried with production data in dev?  Let me ask this: are all the constraints in your prod environment in your dev environment?

Comment: @hvgotcodes: yes. all the constrains of production are in DEV DB. IN fact we used same DDl.  Thanks for reply.

Comment: Guyz, issue resolved!! I found something interesting about hibernate behavior. So I modified the code according that and It worked. "Hibernate insert the data to DB when you associate object to the session not when you call saveorUpdate() / save() method, It is just a call to commit.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a problem with hibernate cache.... inside a single cache flush you can't update twice an object which contain a collection. try to add a session.flush() at the end of your code...

Answer (score 0):

I tried with session.flush solution , but i was still facing the same issue -

then i tried below thing  -  with having updatable=false on my id column - 
and now it seem to work for me - you may try out this solution and see if it works

```
@Id
@Column(name = "MY_COLUMN_NAME",unique=true,nullable=false,updatable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="MY_SEQ_GEN" )
private Integer id;
```